# Password decryption using XOR algorithm in C#. Program doesn't work for unknown reason

Tags: c#, encryption, xor, password-encryption

The function is that it takes a given password, and a key to reveal the password with. After that it uses XOR algorithm to decrypt the password into a cypher. The cypher is at last printed out to the user.

But it prints out nothing. I have found that if i input digits instead of letters in either password or key it prints out all the chars in their int representations

```
Console.Write("INPOUT YOUR PASSWORD: ");
string password = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("INPUT YOUR KEY TO HIDE YOUR PASSWORD WITH: ");
string key = Console.ReadLine();

char[] passwordChar = password.ToCharArray();
char[] keyChar = key.ToCharArray();
int countForKey = 0;

StringBuilder cypher = new StringBuilder(passwordChar.Length);

for(int i = 0; i < passwordChar.Length; i++)
{
    char temp = (char)(passwordChar[i] ^ keyChar[countForKey]); //Doesnt work

    cypher.Append(temp);

    countForKey++;

    if(countForKey == key.Length)
    {
        countForKey = 0;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("The password cypher is: {0}", cypher);
```

Comment: The value of `temp` can be any number and might not correspond to a printable character.

Comment: What is wrong?  Code look correct.

Comment: What doesn't work?  The code seems to work for me, but as Klaus says, sometimes the characters are not printable.

Comment: If you put your expected and actual results into your question, it will be clear what is wrong. Something like: **Expected result:** `A readable encrypted password is printed.` and **Actual result:** `Nothing is printed, or numbers are printed.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting unexpected output is because when you XOR some characters, the result will not be printable.

For example, consider XORing 'W' and 'A':

```
  Char code
W 0101-0111
A 0100-0001
  ---------
  0001-0110
```

The resultant char code, 00010110, is "SYN" (Synchronous Idle), which is NOT a printable character, and will result in either a blank or a box character output (not sure which).

Another example:

```
  Char code
X 0101 1000
a 0110 0001
  ---------
9 0011 1001
```

In this case, XORing `X` and `a` results in `9`.

Comment: But how come when i input large or small charracters in both "key" and "password" it doesnt print out anything. But when i input small charracters in one and large charracters in the other it does print out?

Comment: @Zero_Digits It depends what the result of the XOR is. Write down the codes for the two characters and compute the XOR value and look it up in a character table to see what should come out.